# Why is my computer struggling with Mudbox?

Tags: mac, memory, graphics-card, upgrade, macbook-pro

I'm running a early 2011 MacBook Pro 15", i7 2.2 GHz, 4 GB RAM, ATI 6750m, with Mudbox 2014. Low level subdivisions are fine but once I start adding more detail, painting, posing, etc its nearly impossible to work.

Anyone experienced with this software can you please chime in. I will be using this and many more entertainment design programs heavily. Is RAM the bottleneck here or is the mobile GPU more of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your running a pretty basic setup when it comes to Mudbox. The more subdivisions you continue to do, the more graphic resources you will need to render your model. While you might see some performance gain with using more RAM, ultimately your limited to what your video card is capable of, and that particular card is only equipped with 512mb of vRAM.

Comment: thanks for the input. I guess it's out of the question on this forum to ask what would be recommended?

Comment: Check out this site for recommended hardware. http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/syscert?siteID=123112&id=18844534 I used to have a setup like yours(sorta), and after about 10 subdivisions I noticed a huge performance loss.